# what's the diff. between the nested and Closure function in python

Tags: python, nested, closures

can you please tell me the diff. between the nested and Closure function??
With simple examples??
Thank you! I can't not understand perfectly the difference.

Comment: What even is a "closure function"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.